# Unable to submit app created with Xcode Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I created an app with Xcode 7.1 beta 3 (7B85), I tried to submit it to the App Store but I could not do it because my app was created with a beta of Xcode.
So I downloaded the official version of Xcode on the Mac App Store (7.0.1 (7A1001)) and I remade all my project with this new version, I created all the swift files and I pasted the text from the old project to the each files of the new project created with Xcode 7.0.1. I thought that iTunes Connect would have no problem because I created the project with a non-beta version of Xcode.
But when I subit my bundle to iTunes Connect, I received this message :

`Chaîne de compilation non valide. Les nouvelles apps et mises à jour d’apps doivent être créées avec les versions publiques de Xcode 6 et SDK iOS 8 ou versions ultérieures. Ne soumettez pas d’apps créées avec des logiciels bêta.`

Here is the translation from Google Translate :

`Invalid toolchain. The new apps and updates of apps to be created with public versions of Xcode iOS SDK 6 and 8 or later. Do not submit apps created with beta software.`

Anyone can help me ?
Thank you !

Comment: Not only should you clean your project, but also go to your "`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`" folder and send that to the trash, too.  Then try rebuilding and resubmitting.

Comment: What is the deployment target ( minimum iOS version required ) of your project ? ( You can see that on the "General" tab, after selecting your target in Xcode

Comment: It is 8.0 so no problem with that I think

Comment: There was no need at all to recreate your project. All you needed is the non-beta Xcode, open your existing project, do a Clean, and Archive. That's it (besides testing of course).

Comment: I opened my project in Xcode 7.0.1, I cleaned it and archived it, but in iTunes Connect, I get the same error message... @rmaddy

Comment: For information, I use El Capitan beta

Answer (score 3):

My application was accepted !
The problem was I use a beta version of El Capitan, so I found how to change the ProductBuildVersion in /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist to an other who was not a beta version (in my case, 14C109), I rebooted my mac, I cleaned the project, I archived it and it was ok !

Thanks to all for your answers